# Variables in External config in Grails

Tags: grails, config

I have an external and internal config in my grails application. Here it is:

**Config.groovy**

```
    grails {
       server = 'abc.com'
    }

    testing {
       test1 = ${grails.server}
    }
```

**External config:**

```
    grails {
       server = 'xyz.com'
    }
```

`testing {
   test1 = ${grails.server}
}`

I want to set the value for `test1` to be equal to the overridden value of `grails.server` but what I see is for `test1` the original value is of 'grails.server' is assigned and not the overridden value as in external config.

So at the end I get for `test1` the original value obtained from the config file
ie.'abc.com' and not the value overidden in the external config i.e.`xyz.com`.

Comment: I saw 'This question may already have an answer here:' on top of question. I thought it was something you added. But looks like that is auto-generated

Comment: I really do not understand the close question votes. There is no answer to the question which will solve the issue. Question is also framed correctly. What else ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want test1 to refer to a property like grails.server you'd do the following:

```
grails {
   server = 'xyz.com'
}

test {
   test1 = ${grails.server}
}
```

Surround any property name in the ${} expression and it will return the value of that property.  Now your question is confusing because you talk about overriding a property, but it's unclear which property are you overriding. If it's grails.server then this answer is fine.  But what's also confusing is the use of test because test is an environment, but I think you are trying to make an abstract example that doesn't imply environments.

**Updated**: How did you specify your external config files?  Did you use `grails.config.defaults.locations` or `grails.config.locations`?  If you used `grails.config.locations` that will allow your external config to override Config.groovy, but if you used `grails.config.defaults.locations` then Config.groovy overrides your external configuration.

Comment: `test` was meant only to show example. I will update the question. I will try your solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your question better.

Comment: I am overriding grails.config.locations